# Storybook 7.3.0 can't render React Component - `Unexpected token '<'`

Tags: reactjs, vite, storybook

Inside of storybook 7.3.0 I am trying to pass a mui icon as a prop to my component.  My react component is working fine on its own by importing the necessary icon in the parent and passing it to the child, but when I try to setup the story I am only getting the error `Unexpected token '<'` inside the storybook render.
This is a Vite project and I'm using `@storybook/react-vite` for the creation of my storybook but cannot figure out how to pass a react component to the rendered component inside my component.  My code is as follows:

```
import Avatar_Story from './Avatar'
import Person2OutlinedIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Person2Outlined'

export default {
  title: 'Molecules/Avatar',
  component: Avatar_Story,
  tags: ['autodocs'],
}

export const Icon = {
  render: (args) => <Avatar_Story {...args} />,
  args: {
    size: 'large',
    icon: Person2OutlinedIcon,
  },
}
```

1. I created a `.babelrc` file with this following:

```
{
  "sourceType": "unambiguous",
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "targets": {
          "chrome": 100,
          "safari": 15,
          "firefox": 91
        }
      }
    ],
    "@babel/preset-react"
  ],
  "plugins": []
}
```

But no change
2. I also tried the following syntax in my story

````
export const Icon = {
  args: {
    size: 'large',
    icon: <Person2OutlinedIcon />,
  },
}
```\
````

Comment: Try and research thoroughly before asking a question.

Answer (score 2):

The issue all came down to a file extension.  `Avatar.stories.js` is what was throwing the error, but `Avatar.stories.jsx` worked.